# Can we show for ordinal numbers that $\alpha\in\beta$ implies $\alpha\subsetneqq\beta$ without axiom of regularity?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

[Von Neumann definition of ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) is that an ordinal is a [transitive set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set) which is well-ordered by $\in$. (To be more precise, the relation $\in$ gives a *strict* well-order on $\beta$. Although there are probably various other reformulations of this definition.)

If we take this as a definition, we can show that $\alpha\in\beta$ implies $\alpha\subsetneqq\beta$.

From transitivity of $\beta$ we get $\alpha\subseteq\beta$. At the same time we have $\alpha\ne\beta$, otherwise we would get $\beta\in\beta$, which contradicts the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

**Question:** Is there a different argument which avoids using regularity? Or is a proof in ZF (or ZFC) without axiom of regularity impossible?

Answer (score 2):

According to the link you posted the definition of Von Neumann doesn't state an ordinal is just a transitive set. It states:

"A set $S$ is an ordinal if and only if $S$ is strictly well-ordered with respect to set membership and every element of $S$ is also a subset of $S$"

So an ordinal has to be transitive and also has to be well ordered with respect to $\in$. So $\beta\notin\beta$ for all ordinals simply follows from the definition of strict ordering, you don't need regularity here.

Comment: I apologize for not including the part about well-ordering by mistake. In any case, how exactly do we get $\beta\notin\beta$? (Did you have something like this in mind? We are given that $\in$ is a strict well-order on $\beta$. So we have $\alpha\notin\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in\beta$. If $\beta\in\beta$, then we also get $\beta\notin\beta$, a contradiction.)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\in$ is a *strict* well-ordering, it is irreflexive by definition (recall that a strict partial order is irreflexive and transitive). If $\beta\in\beta$, then $\beta\in\beta$, and therefore $\in$ is not irreflexive.